# How can i convert a string to dictionary and then sort the dict values in alphabetical order?

Tags: python, string, sorting, dictionary

How can I convert a string to a dictionary without duplicates and then sort the values alphabetically?

```py
string = """Luke:sport\nDick:hike\nLisa:game\nLuke:craft\nDick:hike\nLuke:craft\nDick:craft"""
```

expected output:
`{Luke: [sport, craft], Lisa: [game], Dick: [hike, craft]}`

expected output after sorting values alphabetically:
`{Luke: [craft, sport], Lisa: [game], Dick: [craft, hike]}`

Comment: In this particular case, there's no one-liner shortcut.  What have you tried so far?  It's not really a hard problem.  Split, then loop building a dict.

Comment: i have tried: `dictionary = dict((k.strip(), v.strip()) for k, v in (p.split(':') for p in data.split('\n')))` to make string to dict, but i always get a error: "Valueerror: too many values to unpack(expected 2)

Comment: Right.  That's a data problem.  You have `"\"` after the 5th line, not `"\n"`.

Comment: Shorter: `dct = dict( line.split(":") for line in string.splitlines() )`, so when I said there was no one-liner, I lied.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.